# Writing TypeMapper for map with scalapb

Tags: scala, scalapb

I would like to make `map` in case class generated from protobuf wrapped in `Option`

`case class Foo(aMap: Option[Map[String, String]])`

For that I am trying to use `scalapb.TypeMapper`

```
package some.wrapper
import scalapb.TypeMapper
case class StringMapWrapper(map: Map[String, String])
object StringMapWrapper {
  implicit val mapper = TypeMapper(StringMapWrapper.apply)(_.map)
}
```

And the proto file looks like that:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package some;
import "scalapb/scalapb.proto";
message Foo {
  map<string, string> a_map = 1 [(scalapb.field).type = "some.wrapper.StringMapWrapper"];
}
```

But during compilation I have an error:
`--scala_out: some.Foo.a_map: Field a_map is a map and has type specified. Use key_type or value_type instead.`

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way in ScalaPB to get something inside an Option is to wrap it in a message:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package some;
import "scalapb/scalapb.proto";

message OptionalMap {
  option (scalapb.message).type = "Map[String, String]";
  map<string, string> inner = 1;
}

message UseCase {
  OptionalMap my_map = 1;
}
```

Due to the `type` option on `OptionalMap`, ScalaPB will generate myMap as an `Option[Map[String, String]]` instead of `Option[OptionalMap]`. Then only thing we need to do know is to provide a TypeMapper that will teach ScalaPB to convert between OptionalMap and Map[String, String]. To accomplish that, add the following to the package object `UseCase` is in:

```
package object some {
  implicit val OptionalMapMapper =
      scalapb.TypeMapper[some.myfile.OptionalMap, Map[String, String]](_.inner)(some.myfile.OptionalMap(_))
}
```